# Context Free Grammar for L= { a^n b^m c^m d^2n }, where n and m are >= 0

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory, context-free-language, automata-theory, computer-science-theory

Question: Design Context Free Grammar for L= { a^n  b^m  c^m  d^2n  }, where n and m are >= 0

This is how i made it:

```
s -> ABC ( This is the start symbol generating the entire string. )
A -> aA | null ( Generates the a^n part )
b -> bBc | null ( Generates the b^m c^m part )
c -> ddC| null( Generates the d^2n part )
```

I've solved this question, Can anyone tell me is this correct CFG for above question?

Comment: this is wrong because you can make aaaaabcdd, the problem is with the d variable! HINT: every time you make an a you must make 2 d's. Good luck young Elijah!

Comment: Theoretical questions may be better to ask on the Computer Science SE site: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ and not on StackOverflow, which is for "questions about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers."

Answer (score 0):

The given language is in fact a context-free language. So, one can provide a context-free grammar (CFG) for it. However, the above-described grammar is not a correct one for the given language. The variables A and C work independently. Therefore, this grammar does not guarantee that the number of d's is twice the number of a's. The following grammar is OK:

```
S -> aSdd | T
T -> bTc | epsilon
```

First, two d's are generated for each terminal a. When the variable S finishes generating the beginning and end of the string, the variable T starts making the middle part.